# Why I can't download PyAudio in mac m2 using pip3

Tags: python, terminal, pyaudio

## Why I can't download PyAudio in mac

I have already installed homebrew but I can't use brew command line in my mac terminal and also why I can't install PyAudio. Every time this error came out

```bash
Collecting pyaudio
  Downloading PyAudio-0.2.14.tar.gz (47 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 47.1/47.1 kB 1.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pyaudio
  Building wheel for pyaudio (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for pyaudio (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [18 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/pyaudio
      copying src/pyaudio/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/pyaudio
      running build_ext
      building 'pyaudio._portaudio' extension
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/src
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/src/pyaudio
      clang -fno-strict-overflow -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -DMACOS=1 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/opt/homebrew/include -I/Users/raghavmaurya/Desktop/Github-Work/python/Desktop-Assistant/env/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/include/python3.12 -c src/pyaudio/device_api.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/src/pyaudio/device_api.o
      src/pyaudio/device_api.c:9:10: fatal error: 'portaudio.h' file not found
      #include "portaudio.h"
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
      1 error generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyaudio
Failed to build pyaudio
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyaudio, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

[notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.2.1 -> 23.3.2
[notice] To update, run: pip install --upgrade pip
```

I also unable to use `brew install portaudio` it means portaudio is not installed in my mac. If I try to install using brew then this error came out

```bash
zsh: command not found: brew
```

Answer (score 1):

"/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)""
Paste that in a macOS Terminal shell prompt.
You can use brew now.

Comment: The question states they've already installed Homebrew, but the error does strongly imply they either haven't or something went wrong during the installation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).